# How can I set the cell's font in a Tablix expression based on a value in Microsoft Report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, expression

I've a tablix with alot of rows. 
I use `=Fields!LedningLaengde.Value` to set the value in the cell, that's on a row in the Tablix..

The new thing, is that the font need to be red if `=Fields!LedningLaengde.Value` is equal to `-1` how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Color property of the cell, use the following formula:

```
=IIF(Fields!LedningLaengde.Value = -1, "Red", "Black")
```